# New Error is coming from Docusign APi, Anythinh changed?

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting the below error, I am using the same application for last 6 months, and I haven't seen this

com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 401 with response Body: '{
    "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
     "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
     }'
please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part of this error is the last half of the "message" - `an integrator key was not specified`.

What authentication workflow are you using? If you're using Legacy Header auth, the `integratorKey` parameter was not parsed successfully. If you're using one of the Account Server token workflows (JWT or OAuth), this likely means you were missing an `Authorization` header.